# Converting a numpy recarray to pyarrow.Table

Tags: python, numpy, pyarrow

I want to convert a numpy recarray to a pyarrow.Table. Is there a recommended method of doing this?

Converting through a pandas DataFrame is easiest:

```
ra = ... # some recarray
T1 = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(ra))
```

but seems like it should add unnecessary overhead. I've tried `from_pydict` and it seems to work, although somewhat hacky:

```
ra = ... # some recarray
T2 = pa.Table.from_pydict({k:ra[k] for k in ra.dtype.fields.keys()})
```

If I try timing these two in a somewhat realistic example, the `from_pydict` approach is much faster:

```
c:\>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import pyarrow as pa
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> np.random.seed(123)
>>> rectype = np.dtype([('timestamp', np.int64),
...                     ('category', np.int32),
...                    ])
>>> nrows = 20000
>>> rawvals = np.random.randint(1000,size=(nrows,2))
>>> ra = np.array([tuple(row) for row in rawvals], dtype=rectype)
>>> T1 = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(ra))
>>> T2 = pa.Table.from_pydict({k:ra[k] for k in ra.dtype.fields.keys()})
>>> (T1.to_pandas() == T2.to_pandas()).all()
timestamp    True
category     True
dtype: bool
>>>
>>> import timeit
>>> def f1():
...     return pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame(ra))
...
>>> def f2():
...     return pa.Table.from_pydict({k:ra[k] for k in ra.dtype.fields.keys()})
...
>>> timeit.timeit(f1,number=1000)
1.4761637000000007
>>> timeit.timeit(f2,number=1000)
0.05712700000000126
```

Is `from_pydict` the better approach in this case? Does it have any disadvantages?

Comment: The `dict` approach ends up treating each field as a separate array.  That's a reasonable way of working with structured arrays.  I don't know anything about `pyarrow`, but unless there's something in its documentation to the contrary, it doesn't know anything special about structured arrays.

Comment: The `from_pydict` method looks fine to me. It seems that pandas' conversion from a record array to pandas.DataFrame is suboptimal (since the conversion from DataFrame to pyarrow.Table is certainly optimized)